# Rearrange a logarithmic equation to solve for a log variable

Tags: logarithms

I have the following equation that is used in target strength-length relationships in fish.

Equation:

$TS= 20log_{10}(L) + b_{20}$

I have values for $TS$ and $b_{20}$ aad trying to solve for $log_{10}(L)$. I rearranged the equation but am unsure I did it properly and am getting weird answers. Here is the resulting equation:

$L= 10^\frac{(TS + b_{20})}{20}$

Is this correct? I found a resource online that said I had to multiply the value by 10 before I did this but that doesn't make sense to me. Also, the $TS$ values are in log form in the rearranged equation, should they be converted to linear before going in? Or is the rearranged equation already accounting for that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you are adding rather than subtracting?

Comment: Do you mean adding the $b20$? That is simply how the equation is written out in the literature.

Comment: I would have thought $TS= 20\log_{10}(L) + b_{20}$ implied $L= 10^{(TS - b_{20})/20}$

Comment: You could do that as $b_{20}$ is almost always negative. I'm just following it as it is accepted in the literature. ( https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/abs/10.1139/f79-216 )

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean that I should change it to subtraction rather than addition regardless considering it's been rearranged?

Comment: My point is that if $x=y+z$ then $y=x-z$ not $x+z$

Comment: You'd be correct, I completely missed that. I changed it and it's producing values that make sense. Thank you very much.